# Jenkins slave is going offline

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

I have Jenkins slaves connected with master and after some intervals my Jenkins slave is going to offline and whenever its going to offline I am manually running the Jnlp command(Run from slave command line:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://abc.ap.com:8080/computer/Wkaakkaak/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <REDACTED>
```

in slave machine to connect with master but every time I can't login to slave and run the command.Is there any way to run my Jenkins slave automatically.I have configured slave and the Launch method is launch slave agents via java web start.Don't know how to resolve the issue.Could any one please help me out on this? My Jenkins version is 1.585.

Comment: Haven't you installed the slave as a service? You dont have login each time and run the command. Please follow the steps here:https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Comment: Is there any way to avoid Jenkins master restart as my Jenkins master is connected with many slaves and continuously running jobs.So please suggest the ways without restarting Jenkins master.As I told my Jenkins master version is very old.One more doubt here,I just created Jenkins slave in master and connected with slave but not sure whether I need to install Jenkins in Slave as well.Please let me know.